# Execution of geolocation script stops till user accepts or rejects location access

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I am using HTML5 geolocation to get the user location. If the user accepts to share the location, call gets completed with high accuracy and if the users opts not to share the location, fallback mechanism is preferred(Error case or reject).

The problem is if user do not select any option.Then no method gets executed. Is there a way to set if user do not allow or reject the location access, fallback method should be called? I tried passing timeout of 20000(20 sec) but it was of no use.

Can someone help how to proceed in such cases?

Please see the code as below:

```
//function to get device location
function getLocation(successCallback, showError, locFallback)
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, showError, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 });
    }
    else
    {
        locFallback();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var coord;

    function setLocation(position) {
        coord = position.coords;
        getLocationsData();
    }

    function getLocationsData() {
            //some code which uses ajax to load data based on co ordinates
    }


    function deviceLocFallback() {
        //some code which uses geoIP database or 3rd party to get less accurate co ordinates
        coord = fromFallback;
        getLocationsData();

    }

    $.ajax({
        //some code which runs initially, ajax call to server, below code runs in callback of ajax
        getLocation(setLocation, deviceLocFallback, deviceLocFallback);

    });
});
```

Comment: I assume your code was copy/pasted from somewhere and redacted a lot, as you've got mis-matched braces and brackets all over the place

Comment: But fallback mechanism do not need to access device location, right? like geoIP databases. At least request should timeout in some time so that "access not granted" or "error" scenario will run

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: yes, I have deleted a lot of code, and kept just the relevant part, I will modify the code to match braces, thanks